# Cannot register file or assembly after working on solution on different machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, solidworks

Visual Studio Community 2019. I sometimes work from home on the weekend (I know, I know!). When I do I commit my work and then sync from home. My project uses references to an installed program and I have an older version of that program installed at home. My project is run as admin and registers com as interop.

I did some work at home and committed. I synced at work and now I am getting:

> Could not load file or assembly 'SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished,
> Version=28.1.0.74, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89a97bdc5284e6d8'
> or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
> specified.    DispensingAddIn C:\Users\erics\source\repos\TestingEFClassLibrary\TestingEFClassLibrary\RegAsm

I have removed all references to Solidworks and re-added them but that doesn't seem to help. I have also looked at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-broken-references?view=vs-2019). None of those seem to fit my issue.I checked in the csproj file and the path to the references are correct but no version is called out.

Questions:

1. How do I resolve this issue to press on today?
2. How to work in both places when the environment is different on two different machines?

Comment: Does `v28.1.0.74` exist on your work machine? If not you have to use a binding redirect, I would say. For .NET Framework assemblies, the tool _Fusion Log Viewer_ (`FUSLOGVW`) is very helpful

Comment: @mu88 - No, v28.1.0.74 exists at home. v29.4.1.1 exists at work where I am working now.

Comment: Then I think you have to use Bindings Redirects ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions))

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in my case. One of my NuGet packages also referenced SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished. I found this my using "Optimize References". I uninstalled the Nuget package and reinstalled it again. That resolved the issue.